# Upload dataset from google drive to Kaggle

Tags: google-colaboratory, kaggle

How to upload dataset from google drive to Kaggle Datasets via Google Colab ?

I tried my file drive shared id in kaggle remote files section but it didn't work.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKUkq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Get your kaggle json file from Kaggle -> Your Profile -> Account -> API -> CreateNewToken

2 - Create New Colab notebook in drive

3 - Connect your drive to notebook

4 - Copy kaggle.json file and specify path.

```
import os
os.environ['KAGGLE_CONFIG_DIR'] = "/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabNotebooks"
# my kaggle.json file in /content/drive/MyDrive/ColabNotebooks
```

5 - Initiate dataset metadata

```
!pip install kaggle
!kaggle datasets init -p /content/drive/MyDrive/ColabNotebooks/Resized
# my dataset in Resized folder.
```

6 - Edit dataset metadata

```
{
"title": "Augmented HardHat-Vest Dataset",
  "id": "muhammetzahitaydn/augmetned-hardhat-vest-dataset",
  "licenses": [
    {
      "name": "CC0-1.0"
    }
  ]
}
```

7 - Upload your dataset, In my case my dataset in 'zip' format. I used '--dir-mode skip'. But if your dataset not zipped and you want kaggle zip dataset for you use '--dir-mode zip' argument.

```
!kaggle datasets create -p /content/drive/MyDrive/ColabNotebooks/Resized --dir-mode skip
```

[dataset uploaded in 4 minutes !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWqy8.png)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, it worked in my case. Just remember making the file sharable before using the code given below.

```
!conda install -y gdown

!gdown --id {FILE ID}
```

Eg: `https://drive.google.com/file/d/{FILE ID}/view?usp=sharing`

Credits: [how to import data from google drive into kaggle notebook](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-import-data-from-google-drive-into-kaggle-notebook-3af68a1f0d4)

Comment: Thanks for answer but in my case, I want to upload my dataset specifically on Kaggle platform. In other words, I want other users see my dataset on https://www.kaggle.com/datasets . You can say download your file from drive and upload to Kaggle but my upload speed very slow and this method save me a lot of time.